# Reordering data frames by character in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in r that looks like this:

```
    Wave_Expo   Tide_Zone   avg
1   HighEx      High      5.750000
2   HighEx      Low       5.333333
3   HighEx      Mid       7.833333
4   LowEx       High      4.083333
5   LowEx       Low       5.916667
6   LowEx       Mid       4.916667
7   MidEx       High      4.583333
8   MidEx       Low       5.833333
9   MidEx       Mid       4.090909
```

i've been trying to rearrange it by the `Tide_Zone` column so it goes low,mid,high whilst keeping the exposure column in order but have had no luck. I feel there must be some simple way. Any help?

Comment: Is High, Low, Mid really the order you want for Wave_Expo?

Comment: Are your columns strings or factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the order of each factor using  `levels`:

```
dat$Tide_Zone = factor(dat$Tide_Zone, levels = c("Low", "Mid", "High"))
dat$Wave_Expo = factor(dat$Wave_Expo, levels = c("HighEx", "LowEx", "MidEx"))
# the default is alphabetical, which is how your Wave_Expo column are ordered
# I included that line just to make it clear, you could change it...
```

Reorder the data sorting first by Wave_Expo, then Tide_Zone.

```
dat = dat[order(dat$Wave_Expo, dat$Tide_Zone), ]
```

If they start as characters, I would recommend doing this process, then adding an `id` column in this desired order, and then converting back to `character` if needed. Then, if you need to re-order again, this order is preserved in the `id` column.